# How to correctly expose REST APIs for Cassandra entities

Tags: rest, http, url, cassandra

While I know that exposing your database dependent IDs is not recommended and it seems to be easily avoided with classical relational databases, I wonder how to avoid an performance impact when working with nosql database where search indexes are to be avoided and complex (long) composite keys should not be exposed over endpoints.

E.g. in Cassandra the available queries are linked to the database schema, so without adding indexes, how to realize APIs which operate on such entities and therefore their corresponding (very long composite) IDs?

For example how could a REST API be realized to check for the existence for an entry in a table which could look like:

```
TABLE A (
  ...,
  PRIMARY KEY ((pk1, pk2), ck1, ck2, ck3, ck4, ck5)
)
```

The corresponding endpoint would look like this (or at least somewhere contain all the primary key components in the URL)

```
   GET /v1/A/pk1/pk2/ck1/ck2/ck3/ck4/ck5
```

Which looks complicated, and if querying for a list of items would quickly lead to very long URLs.

How is this problem dealt with usually?

Comment: In cassandra, your query has to include the partition key. For your example the partition key is pk1 and pk2 with = operator. The clustering columns (ck1, ck2, ..., ck5) are used for ordering the data and adding some other filtering using =, <, > operators. The partition key it's used to determine the nodes to which the data belong and the clustering columns are used to control how data it's sorted in the partition. If by index you mean the partition keys, your query must include it.

Comment: I meant that I have to include all (or at least the partition keys) in my queries, which means I have to expose them via REST. I wanted to know if that can be avoided without using additional indexes (e.g. SASIs).

Comment: Could you describe a little bit more your thoughts on using additional indexes? I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Also, I have one additional comment regarding SASI: as far as I know it's marked as experimental and it's not recommended for production use.

Comment: E.g. `GET /v1/A/1/` looks like a nice way to query for the A ressource with ID 1, but since the IDs of the A entity are more complicated it would like this `GET /v1/A/pk1/pk2/ck1/ck2/ck3/ck4/ck5` or some concatenated version of the id. I wanted to ask how this is typically handled without creating additional indexes (to realize linear ids).

Comment: You don't have to manually create extra indexes on the columns that define the primary key. All data access (insert, update, delete) in CQL operates in terms of row so they will all need a primary key.

Comment: I updated my original question, I hope it's more understandable.